Looking for a way to use webpack to concatenate tsc generated files
The question is simple: I have 2 Typescript files, I want to use tsc to generate JS and then webpack to concatenate both to an output file.
No visible modules, no dynamic loading via require, no wrappers.
Just take the output of tsc and join packs of files into out files.
I tried countless plugins for webpack, using /// <reference to make a module free js file, instead of import.
Reduced the overhead, but still does not work as I want.
file1.ts:
console.log("file1.ts");
class classA { a() { console.log("file1"); }}

file2.ts:
console.log("file2.ts");
class classB { b() { console.log("file2"); }}

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bootstrap': [
      './ts/file1.ts',
      './ts/file2.ts',
    ],
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: [ 'ts-loader' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].min.js',
  }
};

Desired output: concatenated file1.ts and file2.ts (the JS is the same as the input TS).
Running npx tsc in the root generates the 2 js files as expected, just the concatenation without wrapping is not working.
Output currently is:
console.log("file1.ts"),console.log("file2.ts");

which kind of misses the important parts.
Similar results with the real files, sometimes the content of one file is included, not the others in the list, and with a function(){...} wrapping or other stuff (depending on settings).
I've previously done this via other task-runners and wanted to migrate to webpack.
Previous grunt workflow: watch js => compile ts tree to js tree => concat in packs => uglify packs => me happy.
And I know, this will clutter the global namespace, but this is exactly the intended use case. I want to provide global classes and functionality. A "i = new classA();i.a()" should work.
Please no discussion about that, just the question about how to do it.

I don't think any bundlers support this because it wouldn't be guaranteed to be valid code. You could have const foo = 1 and const foo = 2 in two different files and that would be totally valid. But if you just tack them together then it's a syntax error because you can't redeclare a variable in the same scope. Assuming you have a way to handle that, you could just have a script to concatenate the TS files together before compilation, maybe, but then you're asking for some other problem later. I know you don't want to discuss "why" but this smells like: https://xyproblem.info/

Also, your classes are likely missing due to tree shaking. They aren't used or exported, so the bundler may be pruning them. If you add new classA().a() I bet it will end up in your output.

Thanks for the replies. Yes, in the examples it might be a tree shaking issues, but this an issue in the real world as well. These are support classes that are not used here. Other JS/TS outside the webpack build will use it, that's why I need it in the global scope. About the xyproblem: I gnerally agree, this can be an issue, here it's shortened and not showing the full project. The issue is still described as well as my fav solution and the prev solution using grunt + concat works excellent. Well, not in webpack, at least I did not figure out how.

So it seems that it is not possible with current webpack (5.95.0).
According to the source in webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptModulesPlugin.js Line 873+, an IIFE will always be set if I use more than 1 entry point (which in turn is needed to get all my source files in. Not using the import magic.)
There is no config option to overwrite this and patching webpack is not an option. So using custom scripts to to 33% of webpack's job (combining the tsc output), I can let the scripts do 100% of the work and I get rid of webpack and back to stupid task runners :(
